# How to subtract each item in a group against other items in group in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of transactions per company.  If company, transaction date, and transaction type are the same and the difference between one record's transaction price is greater than .25% with another record's of the same company, transaction date, and transaction type, then I need to select the two (or more) records.

I know I need to use group by to do this, and I will probably need to join the table to itself, but I am struggling to come up with an approach here.  How should I do this?

```
Transaction_ID | Company | Transction_date | Transaction_Type | Price
1              | A       |   01/01/2017     |       BUY       |   30.01
2              |   A     |     01//01/2017  |         BUY     |       37
3              |   A     |     01/02/2017   |         BUY     |      31
```

Comment: Can we see some data please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.Company = t.Company and
                    t2.Transaction_date = t.Transaction_date and
                    t2.Transaction_Type = t.Transaction_Type and
                    t2.Price not between t.Price / 1.0025 and t.Price * 1.0025;
```

Comment: Question:  After reviewing more closely, select t.* does not quite do what I want, however, select * does do what I want.  Why is that?

Comment: For this example, they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
Select t1.Trasaction_ID as ID1
      ,t2.Transaction_ID as ID2 
      ,t1.Company
      ,t1.Transaction_Date
      ,t1.Transaction_Type
      ,t1.Price as Price1
      ,t2.Price as Price2
From transactions t1
inner join transactions t2
   on t1.Company = t2.Company
   and t1.Transaction_Date = t2.Transaction_Date
   and t1.Transaction_Type = t2.Transaction_Type
where ABS(t1.Price - t2.Price) > (t1.Price * 0.0025)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to use `group by` to do this, because you do not talk about group, instead you specify condition between 2 records.
As you said, the condition is: same company, transaction date, and transaction type for the 2 records, and .25% price difference (you might want 25%, because .25% is very small difference).
You should specify your goal more precisely. You said, you want the 2 or more records. As you see, you have one answer which gives records from your table, and an other answer, which combines 2 records, which fulfill the conditions.
One solution which can do what you have asked:

```
select distinct t.*
from yourtable t
where exists (
  select 1
  from yourtable t2
  where t2.Company = t.Company and
        t2.Transaction_date = t.Transaction_date and
        t2.Transaction_Type = t.Transaction_Type and
        t2.Price not between t.Price / 1.0025 and t.Price * 1.0025
)
```